# A Program to find result by giving Power and Exponent as STDIN, Result as STDOUT

Tags: java, exponentiation

I wrote a Java Code to find the result for exponents and powers. It works for smaller exponents and kind of smaller powers, lets say if power is 10 to 20 range. But the real problem happens when I try to larger numbers like 100 and 20, the result doesn't even make any sense.And I will post you the "Making-no-sense" results, so that you may understand why this is happening and help me. And my code goes here

```
import java.util.*;

class Exponentiality{

    public int exponenting(int power,int base){ //This exponenting method returns the value of result
        int a=power;`
        int b=base;
        int temp=1;
        for (int i=1;i<=a;i++){
            temp=temp*base;
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){ //Main method goes here
        Scanner scnObj=new Scanner(System.in);
        Exponentiality obj=new Exponentiality();
        System.out.println("Enter the Power"+":");
        int pow=scnObj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the base"+":");
        int bas=scnObj.nextInt();
        int result=obj.exponenting(pow,bas);
        System.out.println("The result is"+" "+result); //Result prints here
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Variable types have ranges. You’re going over them. You might want to try a different type.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Sir, Even if I take long as a variable's data type, would it allow me to evaluate 2000^3000.? Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, long also has its range. There are types that allow larger values to be used. Maybe BigInteger is of use?

Comment: Yes, I guess It would be Sir.